# fluentd exception handling and forwarding to different instances

Tags: fluentd

Problem I am facing is, I am not using fluentd instance running on my local server.
I am just pushing some data through Java code by connecting to remote fluentd.

Example: 
FluentLogger LOG = FluentLogger.getLogger(app, FLUENTD_ADDRESS, FLUENTD_PORT);
I connect to remote fluentd like this.
and just pushing some data using map.

This way I am connected to only one fluentd remote instance.
what if it fails to connect due to network failure. my messages are lost. Funny thing about it I wanted to catch exception if connection is not established. I am not able to catch exception if connection not established cause Java compiler doesnt understand it.
It's just displaying in the console couldn't connect but its not going to catch block.

If you see connection statement above, from LOG there is noway I can see if connection is open or not example there is LOG.open() I want to write my logs back to file incase connection failure but I don;t find such way to do that.

Can you please share your ideas on this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Possible solutions if you need high availability configurations

- if you can install a local fluentd instance, you can use the `forward` type and this plugin can forward the log to multiple fluentd for HA.
- use a software load balancer (TCP or HTTP)

Reference: http://docs.fluentd.org/articles/high-availability